# How to create open anonymous class implementing interface on Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, aop, aspect

Class in kotlin is final by default, that is not compatible when using aspect (Spring AOP).

@Log - my aspect, logs fun params.

**This code works fine**

```
@Log
open class ConfirmCallbackImp : ConfirmCallback {
    override fun confirm(correlationData: CorrelationData?,
                         ack: Boolean,
                         cause: String?) {
    }
}

@Bean
fun setConfirmCallback(): ConfirmCallback {
    return ConfirmCallbackImp()
}
```

**This code throws exception**

```
@Bean
fun setConfirmCallback(): ConfirmCallback {
    return object : ConfirmCallback {

        @Log
        override fun confirm(correlationData: CorrelationData?,
                             ack: Boolean,
                             cause: String?) {
        }
    }
}
```

Exception: 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class ru.configuration.rbmq.EndpointConfiguration$setConfirmCallback$1

Comment: An anonymous class cannot be open.

Comment: Which AOP tool are you using? E.g. Spring AOP is proxy-based and needs to subclass each target class. AspectJ does not need proxies and I would expect it to work even with final classes (Kotlin or not). Please elaborate. Ideally, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: yet, but the question is how to make an open anonymous class on Kotlin